# How to read JSON response while using $.post to send & receive data to PHP alongwith done & fail functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

**PHP response :**

```
$Result['sendtoshopnumber'] = 'SH-101';

echo json_encode($Result);
```

I want to show this shop no. to the user after the request is saved successfully to the database.

**Jquery code :**

```
var jqxhr = $.post("send_item.php", 
{ 
    ItemID: 120032,
    Qty : 192 

} , 'json')

.done(function(data) {

        alert('your item is sent to shop no. = '+data.sendtoshopnumber);     

         ***here it alerts : UNDEFINED*** 


})
.fail(function() {

    alert( "failed" );

});
```

**The console.log shows what is required but am not able to read that and use it in the javascript. 
console.log output shows : {"sendtoshopnumber":SH-101}**

Comment: post the complete php code. and just check `console.log(data)` first so that you'll know what to access

Comment: It might be like you need add on the top $Result = array();

Comment: and check `network tab` in the console. and check those responses there

Comment: @Ghost : {"sendtoshopnumber":SH-101}  , this is the console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this inside the done block:

```
.done(function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    alert('your item is sent to shop no. = '+data.sendtoshopnumber);   
})
```

Then in PHP:

```
$Result['sendtoshopnumber'] = 'SH-101';
echo json_encode($Result);
exit;
```

Comment: @sqlchild i think it was sent to you as plaintext. you can also use this in PHP `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. so that when you receive it. you wouldn't need to use `JSON.parse`. anyway im glad this helped